# Can someone inform me on how to achieve this type of patina on a furniture project I am working on

Tags: furniture, design, finish, welding

Can someone inform me on how to achieve this type of patina on a furniture project I am working on? I am building a coffee table and tv stand for my bedroom and would like to treat the steel with some sort of finish. I found this piece of furniture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfSMm.jpg) and was wondering how I would be able to achieve this myself. I'm really not sure what to search for because I don't know what this look would be called exactly or the anything about the process. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I am referring to: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfSMm.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an "ebonized" piece. That can be as simple as applying a black pigment or dye stain, or you can get fancy with some woods and do an iron-and-tannic-acid reaction to darken them a bit less unnaturally.

The metal pieces can be bought with dark anodizing or other treatment, painted, or you could try just hitting them with a black marker.

(I'd refer you go the woodworking area, but since this piece appears to be metal and plywood there isn't a lot of woodworking in it. That'd be the best place to learn more about staining and dying wood, though.)

Comment: There will likely be no wood in the piece that I will be working on jut steel

Answer (score 1):

A wax finish using a product like [Briwax](http://www.briwax.com/briwaxpp.htm) can give you good results, and it's relatively easy to use.  Here is a [blog article](https://briwax.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/using-briwax-on-metal/) I found with a quick Google search, but the basic process is:

1. Wax On
2. Wax Off

But seriously, you can brush on the wax or apply with steel wool, let it set, and then buff it off with a cloth or stiff-bristle brush.  It works well for wood and metal.  Because it's a wax finish, I wouldn't recommend it for a piece that might see moisture, so if you put drinks on your coffee table, always use coasters.

Comment: Cool, that is exactly what I am looking for. I will do a test on some scrap steel and see how that turns out.

Comment: Briwax on old iron and steel is one of my favorite looks.  It will burn your hands, and has plenty of fumes.  It will turn to liquid if stored above 100F, and gets harder to use at less than 60F, but it's great stuff.